# How to conduct an ANOVA of several variables taken on individuals separated by multiple grouping variables?

Tags: r, function, loops, anova

I have a data frame similar to the one created by the code below. In this example, measurements of 5 variables are taken on are 30 individuals represented by `ID`. The individuals can be separated by any of three grouping variables: `GroupVar1,GroupVar2,GroupVar3`. For each of the grouping variables, I need to conduct an ANOVA for each of the 5 variables, and return the results of each (possibly onto a pdf or separate document?). How can I write a function, or use iteration, to handle this problem and minimize repetition in my code? What is the best way to extract and visualize the results if you have a large dataset (my real data set has several hundred individuals, and the grouping variables range in size from 6 to 30 groups)?

```r
library(tidyverse)
GroupVar1 <- rep(c("FL", "GA", "SC", "NC", "VA", "GA"), each = 5)
GroupVar2 <- rep(c("alpha", "beta", "gamma"), each = 10)
GroupVar3 <- rep(c("Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo"), times = c(7,8,10,5))
ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y","Z", "a","b","c","d")
Var1 <- rnorm(30)
Var2 <- rnorm(30)
Var3 <- rnorm(30)
Var4 <- rnorm(30)
Var5 <- rnorm(30)
data <- tibble(GroupVar1,GroupVar2,GroupVar3,ID,Var1,Var2,Var3,Var4,Var5)
```

```r
> dput(data[1:10,])
structure(list(Location = structure(c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), .Label = c("ALTE", "ASTR", "BREA", 
"CAMN", "CFU", "COEN", "JENT", "NAT", "NEAU", "NOCO", "OOGG", 
"OPMM", "PING", "PITC", "POMO", "REAN", "ROND", "RTD", "SANT", 
"SMIT", "SUN", "TEAR", "WINC"), class = "factor"), PR = structure(c(16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("ALTE", 
"ASTR", "CF", "CHOW", "JENT", "NAT", "NEAU", "NSE", "OOGG", "PALM", 
"POMO", "REAN", "ROND", "RTD", "SS", "SUN", "WINC"), class = "factor"), 
    Est = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AS", 
    "CB", "CF", "CS", "OS", "PS", "SS", "WB"), class = "factor"), 
    State = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
    ), .Label = c("FL", "GA", "MD", "NC", "SC", "VA"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L), ID = c(90L, 92L, 93L, 95L, 96L, 98L, 
    99L, 100L, 103L, 109L), Sex = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    DOB = c(-0.674706816, 2.10472846, 0.279952847, -0.26959379, 
    -1.243977657, 0.188828771, 0.026530709, 0.483363306, -0.63599302, 
    -0.979506001), Mg = c(-1.409815618, 1.180920604, 0.765102543, 
    1.828057339, -0.689841498, -0.604272366, 0.194867939, -1.015964127, 
    -0.520136693, 0.769042585), Mn7 = c(1.387385913, 0.320582444, 
    -0.490356598, -0.020540649, -0.594210249, -1.119170306, -0.225065868, 
    -1.892064456, -2.434101506, -0.816518662), Cu7 = c(-0.176599651, 
    0.100529267, 1.4967142, 0.094840221, 1.791653259, -0.191723817, 
    -1.526868086, -0.308696916, -2.046613977, -2.228513411), 
    Zn7 = c(-0.338454617, -0.235800727, -0.785876374, 0.114698826, 
    0.202960987, 0.432013987, 0.164099621, 0.609232311, 0.169329098, 
    -0.284402654), Sr7 = c(-0.010929071, -1.616835312, -0.208856, 
    -0.362538736, 1.662066318, -0.893155185, 0.699406559, -0.333176495, 
    -2.026364633, -1.324456127), Ba7 = c(-1.041126455, 0.551165907, 
    0.126849272, -1.069762666, -0.922501551, -1.36095076, 1.57800858, 
    -0.842518997, -1.017894235, 0.265895019)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Ryan can you show the solution for one group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edited answer based on updated question with dput data:***

Assuming the columns representing the grouping variables are 1:5 and 7, and assuming the dependent numeric variables are in columns 8:14, this can be done using a double loop, with no other dependencies:

```r
tests <- list()
Groups <- c(1:5, 7)
Variables <- 8:14
for(i in Groups)
{
  Group <- as.factor(data[[i]])
  for(j in Variables)
  {
    test_name <- paste0(names(data)[j], "_by_", names(data[i]))
    Response <- data[[j]]
    tests[[test_name]] <- anova(lm(Response ~ Group))
  }
}
```

Now you can do what you like with all these tests using `lapply`, such as

```r
lapply(tests, print)
```

I agree with @DaveGruenewald about multiple hypothesis testing though - in fact, this example gave a nice demonstration of why Buonferroni or Sidak's corrections are needed, since there were (as expected) a few "significant" p values among the random data simply due to the number of tests involved.

Comment: I am trying this on my data set. I am unfamiliar with your usage of ^ in `^Var` . I believe I understand what it does, but I don't think it will work in my real data. the variables in the real data are Mg, Mn, Cu, Zn, Sr, Ba, and Pb. what do I need to change where you put `^Var`?

Comment: @Ryan "^Var" means any string beginning with "Var". If the only variables you are interested in are those with chemical symbols, then instead of `grep("^Var", names(data[i]))` you could have `which(nchar(names(data[i])) <= 2)` so that only the variables with names of one or two characters in length are selected. This assumes your other columns have longer names, of course.

Comment: I am still having trouble getting this to work for me. Could you demonstrate the code if the grouping variables were say: `State`, `Location`, and `Class`, instead of `GroupVar1:3`, and with those chemical symbols as the dependent variables?

Comment: OK - before the first line of my code, insert `Groups <- which(names(data) == "State" | names(data) == "Location" | names(data) == "Class")` then replace the line `for(i in grep("GroupVar", names(data)))` with `for(i in Groups)`

Comment: so when I try that it runs without error but nothing happens, and when I do `lapply(tests, print)` it just returns: `list()`

Comment: Are you able to edit your question to show the data in the format you are actually using, since my solution works for your example data? Use `dput(data[1:10,])` and copy the output into your edited question. If you do this, I'll update my answer to give you a working solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205007/discussion-between-ryan-and-allan-cameron).

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing too much about the underlying data, my hunch is this may be improper use of an ANOVA.  I would advise that you post to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) to confirm you aren't breaking any assumptions here.

Regardless, here is the code I would use to tackle the problem presented:

```
# We will use dplyr, tidyr, purrr, stats, and broom to accomplish this
# I am using tidyr v1.0.0.  For older versions you will need to modify code for pivot_longer

results <- data %>% 
  # First pivot the data longer so each dependent variable is on its own row
  pivot_longer(
    cols = Var1:Var5,
    names_to = "name",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>% 
  # Second, pivot longer again, so each row is now its unique grouping var
  pivot_longer(
    cols = GroupVar1:GroupVar3, 
    names_to = "group_name",
    values_to = "group_value"
  ) %>% 
  # group by both group name and dependent variable
  group_by(name, group_name) %>% 
  # nest the data, so each dataset is unique for each dependent and independent variable
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    # run an anova on each nested data frame
    anova = map(data, ~aov(data = .x, value ~ group_value)), # may need to change aov() call here
    # use broom to tidy the output
    tidied_results = map(anova, broom::tidy)
  )

# To easily access the ANOVA results, you can do something like the following:

results %>% 
  # select columns of interest
  select(name, group_name, tidied_results) %>% 
  # unnest to access summary information of ANOVA
  unnest(cols = c(tidied_results))
```

I think you'll also want to use some sort of multiple-comparison correction, such as Bonferroni Correction.  Again, Cross Validated can lead you in the right direction here.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how to do conduct a post hoc (Tukey) test, and visualize the results in a compact letter display in a similar format?

Comment: Here is a nice write-up on doing this: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/84-tukey-test.html.  You can apply these easily with `purrr::map` inside a `dplyr::mutate` call.  If that doesn't get you there, I suggest you open a second question on SO, as this question feels like its having runaway scope.